# How to Count attendance hours on each day by user on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new here.

I have the fallowing data on a table:
[image: Sample Data]

And I need to get the fallowing result:
[image: Expected Result]

I am using the fallowing SQL query:
[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5waV.png)

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Date)
        FROM vRecords
        ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME(Date)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')
SET @sql = N'
    SELECT EmpID, Name, ' + @cols + '
    FROM (
    select EmpID,Name,Date,Time
    from vRecords
    ) a
    PIVOT(COUNT(Time) FOR Date IN (' + @cols + ')) p'
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

What I need to accomplish is to know how many TIMES the user have a record on each DATE

But I am getting wrong result:
[image: Wrong results]

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for all the links but because I am new I can't embed images.

Comment: paste your query as text. you can format them by encasing them between <pre></pre>

Comment: Please explain the logic.  I don't see how the results are derived from the sample data.

Comment: I tried your code and it works.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code as text.

Comment: What I need to accomplish is to know how many TIMES the user have a record on each DATE

Comment: Tried your query as well - seems to work. Are you sure you are referencing the right table / database / server?

Comment: your query is working fine

Comment: I don't know why but when I run the query on my computer I get the wrong result... It doesn't count the Times for the DATE... :'( .... Could it be because of the data type of the columns? I will continue to do testing...

Comment: Which version of SQL you are using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 10.50.1600.1

Comment: What are the column types? Please update your question with create table script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue.

All the problem was related to date format.

The columns were been generated with this format 2018-09-12 and the data was on this format 12/09/2018.

Any way, thanks for the comments.